# Why does UIcollection view destroy the look of Text After scroll

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uicollectionview

Basically i have a uicollection view with uiDynamics, and i feed in text to every cell. When i run, everything looks great ! until i scroll then the text looks deformed !

This is how i insert the texts

```
UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, 20)];
  //  title.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    title.tag = 1;

    [title setText:@"Title"];
    title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Corbert-Regular" size:13];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:title];

    UILabel *description = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, cell.bounds.size.width-100, 40)];
    description.tag = 2;

    [description setText:@"description"];
    description.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Corbert-Regular" size:16];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:description];
```

[image: Before]
After scroll:

[image]

Comment: I am also facing similar kind of issue, the issue is when i am trying to scroll the collection view each time the labels width get changed as I am using [label sizeToFit] but why this is happening not sure.